# Java - Import .csv to database - Exclude first row

Tags: java, sql, database, csv, import

I'm importing database values from a .csv file. However, the first row in the .csv is actually the names of the tables' columns, and my importer updates the database with that being the first row. And that messes up the queries that I'll do later with it. Please help how can I prevent this?

My code of my .csv importor

```
try
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("v.csv"));
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        String[]value = line.split(",");
        String sql = "INSERT into main ([Ticket #], Status, Priority, Department, [Account Name]) "
                + "values ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"','"+value[3]+"','"+value[4]+"')";
        System.out.println(sql);
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        try
        {
            pst = db.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }finally{
            if(pst != null){
                pst.close();
            }
        }
    }
    br.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not reading very first line..

```
As answer is given above... 

String line;
line=br.readLine(); //read the line and do nothing with the line
while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String line;
line=br.readLine(); //read the line and do nothing with the line
while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

it's simple, Read the first line and then start the while loop.

```
br.readline();
while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
```